# system.data.sqlclient.row' error is coming while looping throw the data grid view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am working on vb.net windows application
I have a data grid view..in update button i wrote the code like this

```
Private Sub btnupdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnupdate.Click

        Dim cid As Integer
        Dim dtid As Integer
        Dim cmpname As String
        Dim dtname As String
        Dim dtPhone As String
        Dim dtEmail As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
            Dim rv = DirectCast(bSource.Current, DataRowView)
            cid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Cid")
            dtid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("dtId")
            cmpname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("CompanyName")
            dtname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("dtName")
            dtPhone = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("dtPhone")
            dtEmail = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("dtEmail")

            adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl SET CompanyName = @CompanyName", con)
            adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("update DepartmentMaster_tbl set dtName = @dtName,dtPhone = @dtPhone,dtEmail = @dtEmail  where dtId=@dtid", con)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", cmpname)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtId", dtid)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtName", dtname)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtPhone", dtPhone)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtEmail", dtEmail)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
End Sub
```

In this code I am facing one issue.. the same time if I updated 3 rows in my data grid view.. that is affecting only last updated row.. what code is missing in this code.. I try code like this also

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In gv.Rows
        ...
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", Row.Cells("cid").Value)
        ...
        adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()  
    Next
```

That time getting error:**system.data.sqlclient.row' is not accessible in this context because it is 'friend'**

any help is very appreciate,Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you looping through DataGridview's rows `For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2`... Where you use your `i`- iterator. And what is `bSource`, where it initialized?

Comment: Bsource is binding source that i declared like this :Dim bSource As BindingSource

Comment: in load event i given code like this: dt1 = New DataTable
        bSource = New BindingSource
        adapter.Fill(dt1) 'Filling dt with the information from the DB
        bSource.DataSource = dt1
        gv.DataSource = bSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first version change code to:

```
...
For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
    Dim rv = DirectCast(gv.Rows(i).DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
    cid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Cid")
...
```

It was updated only last row, because on every loop
you getting always same current row `Dim rv = DirectCast(bSource.Current, DataRowView)`
Now it will loop through all rows